# 14.04lts installed on USB stick goes into screen dim

Tags: 14.04, usb, screen, lock-screen

Installed 14.04LTS on a USB stick and system will randomly dim the screen and freeze up for several seconds like it's going into powersave mode.  I have tried all of the screen settings including the 'NEVER' turn off and changed the power management to 'Don't suspend' but it still does it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the dimming is due to the currently open software waiting for some operation and not responding in the interim. this may be due to extensive reading activity on the USB disk. try copying the data you work on onto the faster HDD.

going for a faster USB drive (USB3.0 and faster/newer system) will help somewhat. but in my experience, does not prevent it from totally not happening.